# Setting up webpack 4.0 to use Google material design SASS with ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: webpack, sass, mdc, material-components-web

I'm struggling to get Webpack 4.0 to compile my SASS which I want to use Google material design SASS files with. I think it is an issue with not being able to access the SASS files in the node_modules folder.

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'); 
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
//entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'react/test/index.js'),
entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'react/test/index.js'), 
path.resolve(__dirname, 'styles/main.scss')],
output: {
    path:path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/webroot/_ui/desktop//js'),
    filename: 'testOutput.js'
},
devtool: 'sourcemap',
watch: true,
module: {
    rules: [

        {
      test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
                //exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material'),
                use:ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['css-loader']
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'style-soutput.css'
    })
]

}
```

I thought by using:

> include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material'),

Would enable webpack to pick up the Material SASS files. but I get the error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
@import 'themeColors';
@import "@material/button/mdc-button";
```

Appreciate any help to be able to include the Google material SASS folder.

Comment: Please read the updated Getting Started guide [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#installing-locally).

Answer (score 2):

As Mentioned in the Google Material Design docs, you need to use custom importer to
 load all material files as shown below.

```
const path = require("path");

function tryResolve_(url, sourceFilename) {
  // Put require.resolve in a try/catch to avoid node-sass failing with cryptic libsass errors
  // when the importer throws
  try {
    return require.resolve(url, { paths: [path.dirname(sourceFilename)] });
  } catch (e) {
    return "";
  }
}

function tryResolveScss(url, sourceFilename) {
  // Support omission of .scss and leading _
  const normalizedUrl = url.endsWith(".scss") ? url : `${url}.scss`;
  return (
    tryResolve_(normalizedUrl, sourceFilename) ||
    tryResolve_(
      path.join(
        path.dirname(normalizedUrl),
        `_${path.basename(normalizedUrl)}`
      ),
      sourceFilename
    )
  );
}

function materialImporter(url, prev) {
  if (url.startsWith("@material")) {
    const resolved = tryResolveScss(url, prev);
    return { file: resolved || url };
  }
  return { file: url };
}
```

then Update sass-loader with below

```
{
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              importer: materialImporter
            },
          }
```

Comment: This gives an error, might have something to do with updates from sass